# Web forwarding with masking navigating through pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net VB site I am hosting at home.  I have a domain with godaddy (for example lets call it www.mywebsite.com).  This is web forwarded with masking to a freeDNS name called mywebsiteMoo:1111 which is in turn forwarded to my IP.  As I have web forwarding with masking turned on the user only sees www.mywebsite.com but I am having trouble and I am sure its something daft.

From the first page of my website there are some links to other pages so for example page2.aspx.  If I use `page2Link.NavigateURL="page2.aspx"`I get a 404 error when it tries to navigate there.

Is there something fundamental I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "masking"?

Comment: it masks the url so it only ever shows www.mywebsite.com

Comment: How is that implemented? Please show the rendered outer HTML. If it's a `<frameset>` or `<iframe>` I strongly suggest you remove this "masking" feature and use the DNS system properly by having your `mywebsite.com` domain-name point directly to your webserver (using `A`/`AAAA` records). If you're using dynamic-DNS then make it a `CNAME` record to the dynamic-DNS entry.